# Marketing Cloud API retrieve Send summary yields empty response

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api

I'm trying to retrieve summary information about an email send (opens, number sent, number delivered, etc.) using the Marketing Cloud SOAP API. The response I get has an overall status of "OK" but none of the requested data in it (it is a fully formed XML response but only includes the overall status and a RequestID).

I've tried several SendIDs with the same result. I *AM* able to retrieve link information (ObjectType "LinkSend") for the same SendIDs.

Thanks for any suggestions.

My SOAP request:

```
      <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <RetrieveRequest>
            <ObjectType>Send</ObjectType>
            <Properties>UniqueOpens</Properties>
            <Properties>NumberSent</Properties>
            <Properties>NumberDelivered</Properties>
     <Filter xsi:type="ns1:SimpleFilterPart" xmlns:ns1="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
               <Property>SendID</Property>
               <SimpleOperator>equals</SimpleOperator>
               <Value>xxxx</Value>
            </Filter>
         </RetrieveRequest>
      </RetrieveRequestMsg>
```

And the response:

```
        <soap:Body>
            <RetrieveResponseMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
                <OverallStatus>OK</OverallStatus>
                <RequestID>xxxxx-xxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx</RequestID>
            </RetrieveResponseMsg>
        </soap:Body>
```

Comment: Do you have any PHP code for this?

Comment: Hi @garek007, I'm not using PHP. Is there anything specific you're wondering about?

Comment: No I just can't help unless there's PHP, never done it with any other language

Answer (score 3):

A support ticket with Salesforce solved this problem. The key is adding a dot in the filter property name between "Send" and "ID":

```
       <Filter xsi:type="ns1:SimpleFilterPart" xmlns:ns1="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
           <Property>Send.ID</Property>
           <SimpleOperator>equals</SimpleOperator>
           <Value>xxxx</Value>
        </Filter>
```

What I find so odd about this is that when I retrieve click data (using ObjectType "LinkSend") for the same SendIDs, I don't include the dot in the filter property name, and it works. But in any case, it's working now so life is good.

Answer (score 0):

This is behavior (OK response with no objects) I often see using clientId/Secret as authentication rather than the newer fueloauth.

Are you using clientid/secret in your soap envelope to authenticate, or are you getting a token then using that?

The difference is:

```
<o:Security xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" s:mustUnderstand="1">
         <o:UsernameToken>
            <o:Username>{{soapUsername}}</o:Username>
            <o:Password><![CDATA[{{soapPassword}}]]></o:Password>
         </o:UsernameToken>
      </o:Security>
```

vs.

```
<a:fueloauth><![CDATA[{token}]]></a:fueloauth>
```

To get a fueltoken, you can make a rest POST call using the clientId/Secret to:

```
https://auth-{stack}.exacttargetapis.com/v1/requestToken
```

with a body

{
    "clientId":"{clientId}",
    "clientSecret":"{clientSecret}",
    "AccessType": "offline"
}

Give that a try and let us know if it works for you.  These is also a Rest api endpoint to obtain the same information that is easier IMO to use than making a Soap call.  Unfortunately, a lot of the Send and Event tracking information is not available via the Rest Api, but the information you are trying to retrieve is.

Comment: Hi Mike, I am indeed using fueloauth. But I wasn't aware there's a REST alternative for this info. I can't find the endpoint. Can you point me to it?

Comment: https://www.exacttargetapis.com/messaging/v1/messageSends/{id}/summary .  The documentation is pretty limited.  You can get all the endpoints on their various services by calling the rest discovery.  For instance, https://www.exacttargetapis.com/messaging/v1/rest for messaging.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help, Mike. Unfortunately I haven't made any progress. When I try the /messageSends/{ID}/summary endpoint it returns a 404 status code. I take that to mean (although I'm not sure) that it didn't find the job ID I supplied. I also tried using the external key for the ESD to see what would happen and that also returned a 404. I also tried to get the /messageDefinitionSends endpoint and that returned an empty array.

Comment: The emails I'm trying to get data for are user-initiated sends, not triggered sends, if that makes a difference. I'm starting to wonder if there might be a permission issue, although I find it odd that I can get all the click data for these sends.